# Create a view with read only option in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to create a view with `read only` option from a table in MySQL community server. I used this SQL:

```
Create view viewName as select col1, col2 from tableName with read only;
```

But I get an error message.
Any ideas?
I have edited it with a screenshot of the error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW viewName AS
SELECT col1, col2
FROM tableName
WITH READ ONLY CONSTRAINT my_view_read_only;
```

Comment: @MichaelPeter You really should provide details on the error messages, else it is unlikely someone here can help you find the right solution.

Comment: @UliKöhler It says: you have an error in mysql syntax check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near read only my_view_read_only